# Initialize a static map

Tags: c++, static

I want to call `readFromMap` without instantiating the `HelperClass`.

So I wanted to check if I can call `readIntoMapFromDataStore` at (some think like) class-load?

So that map is always initialized before calling `readFromMap`?

Initialize static map

```
class HelperClass {

static map<string, string> cache;

static string readFromMap(string key) {
return cache.at(key);
}

static void readIntoMapFromDataStore() {
//read contents into cache from datastore
}
}
```

How to initialize before calling `readFromMap`?

Comment: Your code is missing some important things.  The semicolon after the class.  The definition of the static member (that will determine which constructor is used, the code shown will not invoke a default constructor).

Answer (score 0):

The population of the map should be done by a function that returns a map object, NRVO will eliminate the temporaries.  You connect it via using initialization in the definition of the static member:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> HelperClass::cache{HelperClass::readIntoMapFromDataStore()};
```